# "SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type" error

Tags: com, interop

I have a C++ COM local server and C# client. The server code:

```
// MyStruct as define in the _i.h file
typedef /* [uuid] */  DECLSPEC_UUID("...") struct MyStruct
{
SAFEARRAY * FormatData;
LONG aLong;
BOOL aBool;
}   MyStruct;

// Server method being invoked
STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::Foo(MyStruct* StreamInfo, int* result)
{
  long Length;
  BYTE* Data;
  GetData(Length, Data);
  PackBytes(Length, Data, &(StreamInfo->FormatData));
}
```

`PackBytes` converts the `BYTE` array to `SAFEARRAY`. It is taken from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983795/pass-byte-array-within-struct-to-a-com-object). It sets the boundary & dimension of the `SAFEARRAY`.

The client code:

```
MyStruct myStruct;
int rc = obj.Foo(out myStruct);
```

Where `MyStruct` is imported from the COM assembly. it appears as

```
public struct MyStruct
{
  public Array FormatData;
  int aLong;
  int aBool;
}
```

After running `Foo` appears the error "SafeArray cannot be marshaled to this array type because it has either nonzero lower bounds or more than one dimension" with additional remark "Make sure your array has the required number of dimensions".

When debugging the server code it seems `Data` is properly populated in `FormatData`: as can be seen in screen-shot below. `cElements` equals `Length` and the 18 data pieces are equal to the ones in `Data`.

[image]

Hard-coding `Length = 1` did not help. Removing the `PackByets` call made the error disappear (other fields were passed ok). How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PackBytes` method that you have referenced constructs a `SAFEARRAY` with lower bound of 1. Constructing it with a lower bound of zero may fix the problem:

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bound{ count, 0 };
```

Comment: How would code change if array is `short*` instead of `BYTE*`? I changed `VT_UI1` to `VT_I2` in `SafeArrayCreate`, but it's not enough.

Comment: @grunt Do `memcpy(safearrayData, pData, count * sizeof(short))`

Comment: Did that including defining `safearrayData` as `short*` but getting SafeArrayTypeMismatchException

Comment: @grunt I don't think it matters; you can keep it as `BYTE*`. Maybe post another question if there is a problem.