# SafeArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: com, interop

I have a C++ COM local server and C# client. I have two event methods utilizing `SAFEARRAY` to pass data from server to client:

```
// defenition in IDL file
HRESULT Foo1([in] SAFEARRAY(BYTE) param);
HRESULT Foo2([in] SAFEARRAY(short) param);

// as generated in the _i.h file
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Foo1(/*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY* param) = 0;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Foo2(/*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY* param) = 0;

// actual use 
SAFEARRAY *data1;
PackBytes(byteLen, byteData, &data1);
IMyEvent->Foo1(data1);

SAFEARRAY *data2;
PackBytesShort(shortLen, shortData, &data2);
IMyEvent->Foo2(data2);
```

`PackBytes` converts the `BYTE` array to `SAFEARRAY`. It is taken from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983795/pass-byte-array-within-struct-to-a-com-object). I have used it to write `PackBytesShort` so (total of 4 changes):

```
HRESULT PackBytesShort(ULONG count, const short* pData, /*[ref]*/ LPSAFEARRAY* pResult)
{
    // initialize output parameters
    *pResult = NULL;

    // describe the boundaries of the safearray (1 dimension of the specified length, starting at index 0)
    SAFEARRAYBOUND bound{ count, 0 }; // bugfix: 1 changed to 0

    // create the safearray
    LPSAFEARRAY safearray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_I2, 1, &bound);
    if (!safearray)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    // when there is actually data...
    if (count > 0)
    {
        // begin accessing the safearray data
        short* safearrayData;
        HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(safearray, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&safearrayData));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            SafeArrayDestroy(safearray);
            return hr;
        }

        // copy the data into the safearray
        memcpy(safearrayData, pData, count*sizeof(short));

        // finish accessing the safearray data
        hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(safearray);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            SafeArrayDestroy(safearray);
            return hr;
        }
    }

    // set output parameters
    *pResult = safearray;

    // success
    return S_OK;
}
```

The client code signatures:

```
public void Foo1(Array param);
public void Foo2(Array param);
```

Calling `Foo1` succeeds and client code is reached. `Foo2` fails with SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: "**A mismatch has occured between the runtime type of the array and the sub type recorded in the metadata**". Client code is never reached.

I have tried:

changing from `short` to `int`: in IDL, in PackBytesShort (using `VT_I4` & `int` instead of `short` in 3 places).

Leaving `BYTE` in IDL.

Leaving `safearrayData` as `BYTE*`

Only to get same error. What can be a solution to this? Can any other type but `BYTE` be used? e.g. `INT`?

Comment: sizef(short) ??

Comment: sizeof. the code compiles.

Comment: This is a inter-process call, right? What proxy/stub are you using?